# I want to make an drawing app and I want to zoom in and zoom out whole screen can anyone give me any idea about how to do that

Tags: java, android, zooming

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/zoomInId"
    android:icon="@drawable/zoomin"
    android:title="zoom in"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/zoomOutId"
    android:icon="@drawable/zoom_out"
    android:title="zoom out"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/colorId"
    android:icon="@drawable/color_lens"
    android:title="colors"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />



   <item
    android:id="@+id/lineWidthId"
    android:icon="@drawable/stroke_width"
    android:title="Line Width"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/clearId"
    android:title="Clear" />
```

I want to zoom in and zoom out screen when someone click on zoomIn or zoomOut in menu

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.zoomInId:
            break;

        case R.id.zoomOutId:
            break;

    }



    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

can anyone give me anyidea what method I make and then I will call it from this switch cases. 
I am new in android development. Please can someone help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use canvas and with your controls you can zoom in the canvas

Comment: @masoudvali can you please share code as I am knew with android development I don't how to implement this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can inspire from this https://www.androidpit.com/forum/553589/translating-and-scaling-a-canvas-then-finding-bitmaps-on-touch